# How to do data migration in liquibase for multinant architecture

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

We are having a multitenant architecture whereby single database is shared by multiple tenant

We want to do data migration (Insert,update,delete) operation for each tenant in the same database. Each tenant is partitioned using a discriminatior column. How to run this migration in liquibase?

I saw uploaddata concept in liquibase and also spring batch.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.